# Tab glitch with tmux in archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, tmux, tabs

Bug difficult to explain, as it can have extremely random effects.
But the idea is : when I open a new tab in my terminal using tmux (in tig, vim or cmus for exemple), the text always gets extremely glitchy, and can be placed in extremely random places.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfAq0.png) is an example where the top half are using tmux, and the bottom half is a terminator tab.

And there is my .tmux.conf file, in case it can have any link :

```
new-session -n $HOST
# change key binding from C-b to Emacs style C-x
set-option -g prefix C-x
set-option -g mouse on
unbind-key C-b
bind-key C-x send-prefix

# interface
#------------
# pane
#------------
set -g pane-border-fg black
set -g pane-active-border-fg blue

#------------
# tabs
#------------
setw -g window-status-format "#[fg=white]#[bg=blue] #I #[bg=blue]#[fg=white] #W "
setw -g window-status-current-format "#[bg=brightmagenta]#[fg=white] *#I #[fg=white,bold]#[bg=cyan] [#W] "

#------------
# status bar
#------------
set-option -g status-position top
set -g status-fg white
set -g status-bg blue
set -g status-left ''
set -g status-right-length 60
set -g status-right '♪ #(exec amixer get Master | egrep -o "[0-9]+%" | egrep -o "[0-9]*") | %a %m-%d %H:%M'

#-----------
# Copy mode
#-----------
setw -g mode-keys vi
```

I did not find any clue on any website from anybody having the same problem, either on this website or on the archlinux wiki.

Does anybody have any idea of what I can try to fix this issue ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike what I initially thought, tmux wasn't using my default encoding it seems.

Forcing tmux to use utf8 fixed it.

For those of you who might face the same problem some day, here is what you need to add to your .tmux.conf :

```
set-option -gw utf8 on
```

Noting this problem as solved as soon as available